# XNA Shader Texture Memory

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, hlsl

I was wondering about texture optimization in XNA 4.0.

Will the the contentmanager send the texturedata to the GPU directly when the texture gets loaded or do I send the texture data to the GPU when I declare a texture in my shader.

If that's the case, what happens if I have 5 shaders all using the same texture, does that mean that I send 5 instances of that texture data to the gpu or am I simply telling the GPU what preloaded texture to use?

Or does XNA do the heavy lifting in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything in XNA that you can call `SetData` on stores its data in GPU memory. That is: `VertexBuffer`, `IndexBuffer`, **`Texture2D`**, etc. Shaders themselves are also stored on the GPU.

They start existing on the GPU as soon as you create them (or `ContentManager` creates them for you.)

The GPU has "texture samplers". Conceptually these are *pointers* (references) to a texture in GPU memory. When you set `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = myTexture` (or something sets it for you, like `SpriteBatch` or `BasicEffect`), XNA sets sampler 0 on the GPU to *point* at the memory for "myTexture" (which is already on the GPU). This is so cheap that it's practically a free operation.

So, when you write this in your shader:

```
sampler myTextureSampler : register(s0);
...
tex2D(myTextureSampler, uv);
```

You are saying you want to load pixel data from whatever texture is pointed to by sampler 0.